# Swift, how to resize, add padding and background to an image?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to create so simple image processing on a macOS app using Swift, to start a have a file URL (e.g. "../myFiles/myFile.png"), I would like to add paddings to the image and give it a background.

Here is one example, this would be the original image:

[image: original image]

And this is the final result I would like to obtain:

[image]

Any idea on how to achieve this (preferably applying shadows)?

P.S. I took a look into some swift libraries but they seem very low level (e.g. https://github.com/koher/swift-image), I don't know how to achieve what I want with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a solution using the native APIs the source code of my (now defunct app) is open source:

https://github.com/ospfranco/messer